# php + mysql comment system

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

I'm pretty new to php, and for that matter server scripting in general (so go easy on me)
But regardless of that I managed to create this, the first half of a comment system:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="Comment" action="InsertComment.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
Comment: <br><textarea style="height: 100px; width: 600px;" name="comment"></textarea><br>
<input id="Special_ID" name="id" value="<?php $unixtime = time(); echo $unixtime; ?>">
<!--^Gathers a unique id^-->
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Once submitted -->

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("Blaa", "Blaa", "Blaa");
if(!$con) {
die('Could not connect ' . mysql_error());
}
sql_select_db("Comments", $con);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Posts (Name, Comment, ID)
VALUES('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[comment]', '$_POST[id]')";
?>
```

This is exactly what I wanted, a user puts in their name, a comment, and a unique post id (time stamp) is generated, then it is all sent to mysql. 

But now I'm dumb found as to how I can post this to another page..
I assumed something like:

```
if(ID == [the id of that post]) {
//$_GET the mysql stuff
//Post inside a specially made div or something
}
```

Along the lines of that, but I have no clue how to put that into practise :/
Any ideas?
Oh and **Please** don't suggest an echo type post, I've done that and it's not at all what I want.

**Also this is just the basic code, I don't need suggestions on how to touch it up just yet, also errors in this is only due to my sleep deprivation, the code does work.

Comment: Nice [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) holes. Your time ID is NOT going to work - there's no guarantee that two different users won't load the form at the same time and get the same ID.

Comment: First remove the hidden field with the timestamp and change the ID column to a timestamp column with on update = current timestamp. then add two more columns - ID of the comment (should be primary key with auto increment) and a page_id column. Next add the page_id as a hidden field in the form and use that in the mysql insert statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Marc B has said, you'll first want to fix your [SQL injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) holes using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp). Change your insert statement to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Posts (Name, Comment, ID)
        VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']) . "')";
```

To display your comment, try this

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, Comment, ID
        FROM Posts
        WHERE ID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['PostID']) . "'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<div id=\"comments_container\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<div class=\"comment\">";
    echo "<div class=\"name\">" . $row['Name'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"comment_body\">" . $row['Comment'] . "</div>";
    echo "</div>"
}
echo "</div>";
```

Then [CSS style](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) your DIVs using [IDs and classes](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just an example using mysql_fetch_object

Please sanitize your $_GET data before inserting to MySQL, this is a huge injection security flaw.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE id={$id}"
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)
if(is_object($obj))
{
 echo "Welcome " . $obj->Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A full length example is given here:
http://manzur-ashraf.com/code/auto_commenting_system/Automatic_Commenting_System_and_Email_notification_using_PHP_and_MYSQL.htm

In addition to using a MYSQL database to store the comments, you can also post email to the admin about new comments.